# Is it normal to receive working SMS verification code from strange number Facebook

Tags: facebook

I am Algerian.

Why when I want to reset my Facebook password I receive a SMS from an Algerian phone number (00 213 ...), and not from Facebook? And why sometimes the SMS contain spelling errors?

The six-digit code received by SMS works anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. Facebook will use local SMS gateways when possible, because it's cheaper and faster. Using a California-based SMS gateway to send SMS to Algeria would be way more expensive than using an Algerian gateway.

Spelling errors are the strange part, because those messages aren't meant to be typed, but sent by a computer program. Maybe they are correct and you think it's a mistake. As a non-English native speaker, I sometimes think a word is incorrect but I am mistaken, it could be the case here.